# How do I filter a date row which greater than user-input and lower than user-input

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have `journals_data` table, which contains :

```
ID  |  Name    | Input_date
001 | Example  | 02/06/2016
002 | Example2 | 15/06/2016
003 | Example3 | 02/06/2016
```

And i have a `vb.net` form to indicates user input.

```
Select Period

       Month :       Year :
From : <cboMonth>    <cboYear>
To   : <cboMonth>    <cboYear>

<OKButton> <CancelButton>
```

`<cboMonth>` items contains month name from `January` to `Desember` as `string`.

`<cboYear>` items contains year from the `Input_date` column in `journals_data`.

I want to select all rows from `journals_data` where its Month is greater than the "From-Month" value in the form, and lower than the "To-Month" value, also for year.

I got problem in the `sql` code, where the user input value for month is `string` (like `January`) not `01`.

I have used `DateTime.ParseExact()` and `ToString("00")` technique to convert the `January` to `01` and combine it with the `<cboYear>` value and adding the `01` and `31` as the day value. But it won't work, it shows all the rows in the `journals_data` without filtering the `Input_date`.

Is there another way I can use to fix my problem?

Comment: First, store dates using a date data type

Comment: Consider using DateTimePicker controls for this.

Comment: Calculate month numbers - year * 12 + month and compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to find out what to do, and I got this and it works!

```vb
' To indicates the first day of the month
Dim dayFrom As String = "01"
' To indicates the last day of its month I count the days of its month
Dim dayTo As String
dayTo = DateTime.DaysInMonth(CInt(cboYear.Text), Month(CDate(cbomonthFrom.Text + cboYear.Text)).ToString("00"))
Connect()
DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from journals_data where Input_date >= #" & _
                              Format(DateTime.ParseExact(dayFrom + " " + cbomonthFrom.Text + " " + cboYear.Text, "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "dd/MM/yyyy") & "# and Input_date <= #" & _
                              Format(DateTime.ParseExact(dayTo + " " + cbomonthTo.Text + " " + cboYear.Text, "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "dd/MM/yyyy") & "#", Conn)
DS = New DataSet
DS.Clear()
DA.Fill(DS, "journals")
dgv.DataSource = DS.Tables("journals")
Conn.Close()
```

I'm using `MS-Access` database.

Thanks to all your tips guys.